# Custom time format during edit form->helper

Tags: cakephp, forms, input

i am having a new question again concerning a cakephp form->input problem. iam having records with time fields which i want to enter in a format like "18:35". The timeoption can only be set to "24", "12" or "none". At the time i am adding a record it isn't a problem to enter this format. But if i like to edit a record the time is displayed with seconds like "18:35:10". I am not quiet sure how to reformat this to "HH:MM" format, and if there is a cakeish way to do that.

Thx,

cdjw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqls time field is HH:MM:SS so either you need to reformat it before displaying it, or use char(5) as the field type.

The reformatting option could be done in afterFind() of the model/behavior